# Image, text and background not responsive to a change in screen size

Tags: html, css

Whenever I change my screen size, the text and image is not responsive to that change.

Also whenever I want to add a scroll - the background acts weird and doesn't show the whole page.

Image 1:
[Scrolling horitzontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y4vH.jpg)

Image 2:
[Changing screen size and text isn't showing properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jiz3.jpg)

Html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<div class='comicContainer'>

    <div class='comicBackground'>
        <img src='Images/test1.jpg'></img>
    </div>

    <div class='comicImage'>
        <img src='Images/test1.jpg'></img>
    </div>

    <div class='comicText'>
    <h1>Impact Winter</h1>
    <h2>Published: 26 June 2016</h2>
    <h3 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Writer: Travis Beacham
    </h3>
    <h4 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Penciler: Stephen Green
    </h4>
    <h5 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Cover Artist: Stephen Green
    </h5>
    <p class='breakLine'>In the British countryside, a band of survivors has formed a resistance in the fallout shelter of a medieval castle. Among them is Darcy, a young, headstrong fighter waiting for the chance to prove she can be on the front lines.</p>
    <br>
    <button><center>BUY</center></button>

  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    font-family: 'Anton';
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.comicBackground img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    object-fit: cover;

    filter: brightness(20%);
  }

.comicImage img {
    width: 250pv;
    height: 350px;

    position: relative;

    top: -530px;
    right: -20px;
}

.comicText {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -890px;
    right: -350px;

    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
}

.comicText button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 44px;

  border: 3px solid purple;
  background-color: transparent;

  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.comicText button:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

  @media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .comicBackground img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 105%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        filter: brightness(20%);
      }
  
      .comicImage img {
        width: 350px;
        height: 450px;
    
        position: relative;
    
        top: -710px;
        right: -100px;
    }
    
    .comicText {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: -1170px;
        right: -500px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    }
      
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .comicBackground img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 120%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      filter: brightness(20%);
    }

    .comicImage img {
        width: 250px;
        height: 350px;

        position: relative;
         top: -120px;
         right: 120px;
    
        transform: translate(65%, -200%);
    }

    .comicText {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: -820px;
        right: -50px;
    
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    }
  }


  .breakLine {  
    width: 700px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I tried to change the properties based on screen size - i.e for mobile screen size, I changed the orientation of the text + image - but it doesn't really work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of your issues are related to using [`positioned elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). It's more difficult than it needs to be to get them to be responsive. Your best bet is to use [`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layouts and the CSS [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) prop for your `.comicBackground` instead of an `image`.

I've added [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcayers/c4gzqp8n/4/) with an example of what that might look like.

The key take-aways are:

Changing the way your HTML elements are grouped -- `.comicBackground` now wraps `.comingImage` and `.comicText`

```html
<div class="comicBackground">
  <div class='comicContainer'>
    <img class='comicImage' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/7809122/pexels-photo-7809122.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2' />
    <div class='comicText'>
      <h1>Impact Winter</h1>
      <h2>Published: 26 June 2016</h2>
      <h3 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Writer: Travis Beacham
      </h3>
      <h4 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Penciler: Stephen Green
      </h4>
      <h5 style='font-size: 22px;'>
        Cover Artist: Stephen Green
      </h5>
      <p class='breakLine'>In the British countryside, a band of survivors has formed a resistance in the fallout shelter of a medieval castle. Among them is Darcy, a young, headstrong fighter waiting for the chance to prove she can be on the front lines.</p>
      <br>
      <button>
        BUY
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Removing `positioned elements` and using [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for the layout.

```css
.comicContainer, .comicBackground {
  display: flex;
}

.comicBackground {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.comicContainer {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: max-content;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

Using the `background-image` CSS prop to create a responsible background image using the [`url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) function

```css
.comicBackground {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85), rgba(18, 42, 66, .85)), 
     url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7809122/pexels-photo-7809122.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

*Note: You can define multiple values for the `background-image` if you pass a comma-delimited list. The `linear-gradient` here is just a way of replacing the `filter: brightness(20%);` you had.*

There are some other, unrelated, changes in the fiddle that might be of some value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, except for the smallest size, you need to set your @media queries to have both a maximum and a minimum size. So for example, change the  `@media screen and (max-width: 2000px)` to something like  `@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 2000px)`.

You may also have a typo in your CSS. pv isn't a recognized measurement unit.